# How to utilize a switch statement in this instance?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, switch-statement

I'm writing a program that converts units (ex. oz & lb) to new units of measurement (g & kg). I was going to have the user to input the unit they want to convert from and the value of the original unit. I also set constants to convert the selected units. What I'm having an issue with is using a switch statement to determine what conversion I should use (oz ---> g, oz --->, etc).

Here's the code:

```
    System.out.print("Convert from: ");
    String origMeasure = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Convert to: ");
    String newMeasure = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Value: ");
    double value = input.nextDouble();

    double newValue = 0;

    final double OZ_TO_G = 28.3;
    final double OZ_TO_KG = 0.028;
    final double LB_TO_G = 453.6;
    final double LB_TO_KG = 0.045;
    final double IN_TO_MM = 25.4;
    final double IN_TO_CM = 2.54;
    final double IN_TO_M = 0.0254;
    final double FT_TO_MM = 304.8;
    final double FT_TO_CM = 30.48;
    final double FT_TO_M = 0.3048;

    final String OZ = " oz";
    final String LB = " lb";
    final String IN = " in";
    final String FT = " ft";
    final String G = " g";
    final String KG = " kg";
    final String MM = " mm";
    final String CM = " cm";
    final String M = " m";

    switch(origMeasure){
    case(OZ):
        newValue = (value * OZ_TO_G);
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(value + origMeasure + "=" + newValue + newMeasure);
}
```

}

Comment: What is the actual problem? Please describe it clearly

Comment: I'm having a problem with using a switch statement to determine which conversion (constant) to convert the old measurement to the new one.

Comment: continue what you have starting with

Comment: Sounds like a case for Replace Conditional with Polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Concatinate the two strings together and use that as your case statement. So if the user inputs oz for the initial measurement, and then g for the final measurement, you will have switch(initial + final) to yield: ozg.

Have your case statement check for each:

```
String orig = input.next();
    String end = input.next();
    switch(orig + end){
    case "ozg": //DO MATHEMETICAL FUNCTION HERE TO GET RESULT OF OZ --> G
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a input concatenation + dictionary to do this without a switch statement.

```
Dictionary<string, float> conversions = new Dictionary<string, float>();
conversion.add("OZ_TO_KG", 28.3);

System.out.print("Convert from: ");
String origMeasure = input.nextLine();

System.out.print("Convert to: ");
String newMeasure = input.nextLine();

System.out.print("Value: ");
double value = input.nextDouble();

string conversion = origMeasure + "_TO_" + newMeasure;
float rate = conversions[conversion];
double newValue = value * rate;
```

You have to validate if the conversion exists in order to not raise Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you break down your code , in different classes one for each kind of measurement 
1. One For Height,Weight etc ..(This would break your problem down)
Each of these classes may have a map , which would hold conversion unit eg,
kg-lb(key) -- > 2.20462(value)
m-cm --> 100 etc

You can put in a Parser which would parse the user input. User input can be in the format like ( 10 kg to lb) . parse the user input and create keys(kg-lb) to be used with map and just multiply the conversion unit

Answer (score 0):

If this utility is something that you intend to extend and maintain in the future, I would suggest that you use enums and separate the conversion into two steps through a common base unit:

---

```
public enum UnitType
{
    WGT("Weight"),
    DST("Distance");

    public final String title;

    UnitType(String pTitle)
    {
        title = pTitle;
    }
}
```

---

```
public enum Unit
{
    //Weight Units: base unit for all is GM
    GM(UnitType.WGT, BigDecimal.ONE, "Grams"),
    KG(UnitType.WGT, new BigDecimal("1000"), "Kilograms"),
    MG(UnitType.WGT, new BigDecimal("0.001"), "Milligrams"),
    OZ(UnitType.WGT, new BigDecimal("28.3"), "Ounces"),
    LB(UnitType.WGT, (new BigDecimal("16")).multiply(OZ.baseFactor), "Pounds"),

    //Distance Units: base unit for all is MTR
    MTR(UnitType.DST, BigDecimal.ONE, "Meters"),
    MM(UnitType.DST, new BigDecimal("0.001"), "Millimeters"),
    CM(UnitType.DST, new BigDecimal("0.01"), "Centimeters"),
    KM(UnitType.DST, new BigDecimal("1000"), "Kilometers"),
    FT(UnitType.DST, new BigDecimal("0.3048"), "Feet"),
    YD(UnitType.DST, (new BigDecimal("3")).multiply(FT.baseFactor), "Yards"),
    IN(UnitType.DST, FT.baseFactor.divide(new BigDecimal("12"), 10, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP), "Inches");

    public final UnitType unitType;
    public final BigDecimal baseFactor;
    public final String title;

    Unit(UnitType pUnitType, BigDecimal pBaseFactor, String pTitle)
    {
        unitType = pUnitType;
        baseFactor = pBaseFactor;
        title = pTitle;
    }

    public BigDecimal convert(Unit pTargetUnit, BigDecimal pValue, int pScale)
    {
        if (pTargetUnit.unitType != unitType)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(getErrorMsg(this, pTargetUnit));
        }
        return pValue.multiply(baseFactor).divide(pTargetUnit.baseFactor, pScale, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    }

    private static String getErrorMsg(Unit pSourceUnit, Unit pTargetUnit)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Cannot convert ");
        sb.append(pSourceUnit.unitType.title).append(" (").append(pSourceUnit.title).append(") to ");
        sb.append(pTargetUnit.unitType.title).append(" (").append(pTargetUnit.title).append(")");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

---

So usage might look something like this:

```
public class UnitConverter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.print("Convert from: ");
            String sourceUnitName = scanner.next().toUpperCase();
            if (sourceUnitName.equals("EXIT"))
            {
                break;
            }
            Unit sourceUnit = Unit.valueOf(sourceUnitName);
            System.out.println("Source unit: " + sourceUnit.title + System.lineSeparator());

            System.out.print("Convert to: ");
            String targetUnitName = scanner.next().toUpperCase();
            Unit targetUnit = Unit.valueOf(targetUnitName);
            System.out.println("Target unit: " + targetUnit.title + System.lineSeparator());

            System.out.print("Value: ");
            BigDecimal sourceValue = new BigDecimal(scanner.next());
            BigDecimal targetValue = sourceUnit.convert(targetUnit, sourceValue, 10);
            System.out.println(sourceValue.toString() + " " + sourceUnit.title + " = " + targetValue.toString() + " " + targetUnit.title);
        }
    }
}
```

---

This approach converts in two steps: 1) source unit to common base unit, 2) common base unit to target unit. Without converting through a common base unit, anything other than a very limited number of units and types quickly devolves into an unmaintainable Cartesian product of all-to-all conversion factors